# how to use alias for embedded base 64 images in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have to use Base64 embedded images in my html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'
       src='data:image/jpeg;base64, <!-- Base64 data -->' />
  </body>
</html>
```

but my images size are more than 200k and the `base64 data` part is really huge.
I need to put these image in other tag like `script` and attach them there on run time.

I need something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'
       src='data:image/jpeg;base64, readdata('mybase64imageid')' />
  </body>
 <some-tag id='mybase64imageid'>my base 64 image is written 
 here</some-tag>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that's possible. Do you have a specific issue implementing it?

Comment: "I need to put these image in other tag like script and attach them there on run time." — How would that help? You would still be putting the huge amount of data in the page.

Comment: we have some hosting issue that we cannot put our images on our server

Comment: *"I need to put these image in other tag like script and attach them there on run time."* - Are you just asking how to set the `src` for an `<img>` element in JavaScript?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I have no Idea about creating the alias tag

Comment: What do you mean by `alias` tag? All you need is the `img`

Comment: where should I put those data in my file?

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you need to work on fixing the "hosting issue that we cannot put our images on our server", rather than levering in large base64 images.

Comment: You could use a `template` that already contains `img` elements having the data set as their source, you could put it into your JS in the form of JSON, ... - But it is still unclear what exactly you are hoping to achieve by this? The image data will have to get send to the client either way ...

Comment: I am not exactly sure how you are looking for but to replace 'some-tag' or in case you want to show base64 on page you can use any tag like '<p>', '<div>', '<b>' etc

Answer (score 1):

To add "src" runtime into the image:

```
<img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image' />

<script>
    var img = document.getElementById("base64image"); 
    img.src = "base64 for image goes here";
</script>
```

If you are looking for looping you can go with:

```
jQuery('img').each(function(){
jQuery(this).attr('src', 'base64 path')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're so concerned about making your code un-viewable because of a massive base64 string, why not make a separate file with your string in, and fetch it? Take this example:

Image.txt:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'>
    <script type="module">
       // Fetch using the fetch API
       let res = await fetch("./Image.txt");
       // Get it all as text
       let b64string = await res.text();
       // Set the img SRC
       document.getElementById("base64image").src = b64string;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Since you just updated your question, and you wish to have it displayed in another HTML tag below, just set the tag's ID and set the SRC to it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'>
    <p id="mybase64imageid">data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv</p>
    <!-- Add the 'style="display: none;"' attribute if you don't want it displayed on the page -->
    <script type="module">
       // Get it as string from the Element
       let b64string = document.getElementById("mybase64imageid").innerText;
       // Set the img SRC
       document.getElementById("base64image").src = b64string;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Happy coding!